# SELinux symlinks?

Tags: symlink

SELinux is not allowing me to change the context of a symlink. I get no errors or anything. It just doesn't change the symlink, which I am guessing means it is resolving the symlink and changing that instead? 
coderoot is a symlink:

chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/coderoot

This leaves the context of the symlink the same. When my application references the symlink SELinux jumps in and says no. With SElinux off it works fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the `chcon(1)` man page:

```
   -h, --no-dereference
          affect symbolic links instead of any referenced file
```